# How to route all traffic from a vm (linux guest) to another (win10 guest)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing, vpn

I'm in a situation where I'd like **to work from a linux machine** (linux vm guest) **through another vm** (win10 guest).

**Why?** cause I need a VPN for my work where the VPN client only works with windows (f5 vpn client doesn't pass the antivirus check on the linux machine, don't know which antivirus is supported by the f5 client `f5epi`)

Think in theory there are 2 options, configure the mikrotik for routing all the traffic through the win machine, and the other to configure both vm to route the traffic to each other, but don't know how...

[image]

Comment: theoretically, given that F5 is already configured to route traffic and do snat, can't you just specify F5 as vbox vm router?

Comment: This proprietization of vpn clients really does my head in. Ultimately they're **nearly** all L2TP or IPSEC - but they seem to go out of their way to break any sort of interoperability. Why are you running anit-virus on a Linux machine? And can you name and shame that lousy bit of software? Did you report the false positive to the vendor? A quick google and I found found multiple open-source clients for F5 vpn (gof5, f5vpn-client, f5-vpn-client...) but it seems to be a very vanilla vpn and should be possible to connect with the software already on your device.

Comment: The answer I got from my enterpise (which is a huuuuge one) is: we do not support linux OS...

Comment: @realpclaudio could you be more specific? got the idea, but how to do that... any doc you could point me out?

Comment: Not really into Windows, but there should be some magic wizard to allow other clients to use network connectivity. Once done, as a test just do "route add default gw 192.168.1.115" on Linux box and see at least if packets are coming to Win (tcpdump Linux side and wireshark windows side).